# Iteratively divide column by column plus suffix (pandas)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

In my *for* loop I would like to divide a column by another. The second column's name is dependent upon the first. Example data frame columns look like this:

```
column1, column1_mean, column2, column2_mean
```

I would like to iteratively divide each column by its corresponding **mean column** ( *column1 / column1_mean*; *column2/column2_mean* ).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For a given list of column names `cols = ['column1', 'column2', ... ]`, you can use `.div()` to divide a list of columns by another list of columns, and use string formatting to make the second list of columns based on the first:

```
df[cols].div(df[['{0}_mean'.format(col) for col in cols]])
```

But a simpler way would be to dispense with making the mean columns altogether:

```
df[cols].div(df[cols].mean())
```